# Inserting timestamp into datetime2 columns

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-data-factory

I'm working in Azure Synapse Dataflows, and want to insert a `date` column into our SQL DWH table, where the column is defined as a `datetime2(7)` column.

In the SQL Server table, the values of the `datetime2` column look like a default value of `1970-01-01 05:37:11.0020000`.

First I'm using a derived column to set the "date" column to a timestamp column.

```
coalesce(toTimestamp(toString(ReceptionDateStore, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

Using preview in both the derive activity and in the sink, it looks to be all well:

[image]

However, after running the job I can see that the values in the column are like this:

```
1970-01-01 05:37:11.0020000
1970-01-01 05:37:10.7290000
1970-01-01 05:37:10.9290000
```

I suspect there is something about the format in the derive activity column, but after trying several formats all with the same result, I hope I can get some clues from here

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884)

Comment: Proptip: **never** convert `date`/`time`/`datetime`/etc values to a string (and back again) in SQL - because it's a _lossy_ conversion. So if you ever find yourself doing that, then you should be thinking "this isn't right...".

Comment: Show us your **full** statement, not just your column expression.

Comment: Appreciate the tip! But as Timestamp can only take in strings, I found that to be the only way to make use of the adf derive colum activity?

Comment: @tamiboy777 _"But as Timestamp can only take in strings"_ - I think you're misunderstanding what `toTimestamp` is used for, and why you don't need to use it here. Furthermore, [there isn't any type named `timestamp` in SQL Server, T-SQL, nor PDW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but I cant seem to find any other way to insert my date column into the dateime2(7) column in the sql dwh. ADF looks to be pretty limited in column transformatons and going from date to string to timestamp looks to be "only" way I can find

Comment: what happens if you just insert the value without any unnecessary conversions

Comment: @tamiboy777 We can't help you unless-and-until you share your full `CREATE TABLE` statements (for both your source **and** destination tables).

Comment: Cant insert a date or string into a datetime column, unfortunately

Comment: There's nothing in sql server that should prevent you from inserting a date into a datetime2 column... What's the error you're getting if you just do it?

Comment: Im not getting an error if I dont convert the date, the colum values get transformed;

1970-01-01 05:37:11.0020000
////
1970-01-01 05:37:10.7280000
////
1970-01-01 05:37:11.0020000

Comment: Delved into your statement @siggemannen and seems that Synapse somehow interprets the datetime2 column as a timestamp column(?)

Comment: @tamiboy777 Please answer the questions we have already put to you, otherwise you're wasting your own time in addition to our own.

Comment: Do you need the precision down to nanoseconds? I'm asking before I post an answer

Comment: Your returned data looks as if you are truncating the date from your datetime. Are you sure this is an issue with a datetime into a datetime2 column? Is it possible this is an issue with a datetime datatype being inserted into a time datatype?